# When should I release an object used asynchronously?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an object that encapsulates an asynchronous NSURL request. When should I release it?

```
StrangersRequest *request = [[StrangersRequest alloc] init];
request.strangersListener = strangersListener;
[request send];
```

*Analyze* in XCode says I should release it immediately - but that's not right because it has to handle the URLRequest callback.

What's an appropriate pattern for releasing objects that handle asynchronous events?

I'm guessing I should release when the request completes (`connectionDidFinishLoading`). If so, how can I stop *Analyze* from complaining about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow the `NSThread` model and have the object retain itself until its asynchronous task has completed.

Answer (score 4):

You should maintain a reference to it in the class that uses it and then trash it immediately. Then, your class can remove the reference when it's done. Something like this:

```
StrangersRequest *request = [[StrangersRequest alloc] init];
request.strangersListener = strangersListener;
[request send];
self.strangersRequest = request;
[request release];
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store it in an ivar instead of a local variable.